# Firefox still shows expired cokies in debugging screen

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

Anyone else have this problem. I have a web application that sets a unique cookie via Javascript every time it is accessed. This cookie has a very short expiry time, and should disappear after the user closes the browser.

I cannot use a session cookie for this, as i need the cookie to expire even if the user does not close the browser.

But I noticed that, only in FireFox, no matter how many times i close the browser or reboot the computer, the expired cookies still show up in the debugger (See attached screen shot). It does not happen in other browsers like chrome or edge.

As you can see, there are cookies that has expired months ago, that are still showing up in the debug list.

How can i get the expired cookies to disappear, like what it is suppose to do? And will these extra cookies cause problems in the long run?

[image: Debug screen from Firefox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an open bug (since 10 years ago!): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=576347

Currently, it will only remove expired cookies when a 3000 cookies limit is reached.